# php: the best practice to pass two global arrays to the function to modify them

Tags: php, function, global

There are two arrays that need to be changed within a function.
How to pass that arrays?
The way I know is to declare 2 arrays as global variables within a function:

```
function myfunc(){
 global $arr1;
 global $arr2;
 //do something
}
```

Does it make sense and is it possible to pass two arrays as references instead? How (in case if Yes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can pass them by reference, define your function as follows:

```
function myfunc(&$arr1, &$arr2) {
    // ... modify arrays here
}
```

Just prepend the function arguments you want passed by reference with an `&`.  Now when they are received by the function, they are references.

You do not have to (and should not) put the `&` in front of the variables when you are calling the function as this results in a call-time pass-by-reference notice.  Just pass them to your function as usual `$res = myfunc($first, $second);`

See [Passing by Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can pass the arrays as reference, and that would be preferable to using globals.

```
function myfunc( array &$arr1, array &$arr2 ) {
    // do something
}

myfunc( $someArray, $someOtherArray );
```

The `&` in the function definition tells PHP to pass a reference rather than a value.

Answer (score 1):

I would take another approach (if the arrays are not too big...) to make it clear where the function is called that the original arrays will be changed (although I probably would never changed two global arrays in one function...):

function call:

```
list($array1, $array2) = myfunc($array1, $array2);
```

function:

```
function myfunc($array_x, $array_y){
  //do something
  return array($array_x, $array_y);
}
```